# How to redirect root page to another url in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, redirect

I want my app to start with www.abc.com/#!/abc currently when I type www.abc.com it redirects to www.abc.com/#!. Following are my index.html

```
<!-- views/index.html -->
<section data-ng-controller="IndexController">
    <h1 mean-token="'home-default'">This is the home view</h1>
</section>


// controllers/index.js
angular.module('mean.system').controller('IndexController', ['$scope', 'Global', function ($scope, Global) {
    $scope.global = Global;
}]);
```

I tried changing the routes templateurl from

```
        $stateProvider              
            .state('home', {
                url: '/',
                templateUrl: 'public/system/views/index.html'
            })
```

to

```
        $stateProvider              
            .state('home', {
                url: '/',
                templateUrl: 'public/abc/views/abc.html'
            })
```

which solved my problem from functionality point of view but can I aswell redirect to another url from inside system/views/index.html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can redirect to other url's (called states in ui-router terminology!). This is how you do it...

In index.html file

```
<button type="button" ui-sref="login">Go to login state</button>
```

In controller

```
.state('login', {
  url: "/login",
  templateUrl: "views/login.html"
})
```

Create login.html file

```
<!-- views/login.html -->
<section data-ng-controller="LoginController">
        <h1 mean-token="'login-default'">This is the login view</h1>
</section>
```

And voila!

You can learn a lot more [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki)!

Answer (score 2):

In your config section add dependency for `$urlRouterProvider`

`$urlRouterProvider.when('/', '/abc');`

Comment: OP's using angular UI's "ui-router" and hence the 'ui-router' dependency!